# Как посчитать сколько пар Key-Value экспортировалось из HashMap в Txt?

Tags: java

Как посчитать сколько пар Key-Value экспортировалось из HashMap в Txt?

Comment: hash_map.size()? Ну а вообще уточните вопрос.

Comment: да, точно, как же я не догадался

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод **Hash_Map.size()** используется для получения размера карты, который ссылается на количество пары ключ-значение или отображений в карте.